# Working with a pdf from the web directly in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, urllib, pypdf

I'm trying to use Python to read .pdf files from the web directly rather than save them all to my computer.  All I need is the text from the .pdf and I'm going to be reading a lot (~60k) of them, so I'd prefer to not actually have to save them all.

I know how to save a .pdf from the internet using urllib and open it with PyPDF2. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751197/opening-pdf-urls-with-pypdf))

I want to skip the saving-to-file step.

```
import urllib, PyPDF2
urllib.urlopen('https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf')
wFile = urllib.urlopen('https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf')
lFile = PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader(wFile.read())
```

I get an error that is fairly easy to understand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    fil = PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader(wFile.read())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 797, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1245, in read
    stream.seek(-1, 2)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Obviously PyPDF2 doesn't like that I'm giving it the `urllib.urlopen().read()` (which appears to return a string).  I know that this string is not the "text" of the .pdf but a string representation of the file.  How can I resolve this?

**EDIT:** NorthCat's solution resolved my error, but when I try to actually extract the text, I get this:

```
>>> print lFile.getPage(0).extractText()
ˇˆ˘˘˙˘˘˝˘˛˘ˇ˘ˇ˚ˇˇˇ˘ˆ˘˘˘˚ˇˆ˘ˆ˘ˇ˜ˇ˝˚˘˛˘ˇ ˘˘˘ˇ˛˘˚˚ˆˇˇ!
˝˘˚ˇ˘˘˚"˘˘ˇ˘˚ˇ˘˘˚ˇ˘˘˘˙˘˘˘#˘˘˘ˆ˘˛˘˚˛˙ ˘˘˚˚˘˛˙#˘ˇ˘ˇˆ˘˘˛˛˘˘!˘˘˛˘˝˘˘˘˚ ˛˘˘ˇ˘ˇ˛$%&˘ˇ'ˆ˛
$%&˘ˇˇ˘˚ˆ˚˘˘˘˘ ˘ˆ(ˇˇ˘˘˘˘ˇ˘˚˘˘#˘˘˘ˇ˛!ˇ)˘˘˚˘˘˛ ˚˚˘ˇ˘˝˘˚'˘˘ˇˇ ˘˘ˇ˘˛˙˛˛˘˘˚ˇ˘˘ˆ˘˘ˆ˙
$˘˘˘*˘˘˘ˇˆ˘˘ˇˆ˛ˇ˘˝˚˚˘˘ˇ˘ˆ˘"˘ˆ˘ˇˇ˘˛ ˛˛˘˛˘˘˘˘˘˘˛˘˘˚˚˘$ˇ˘ˇˆ˙˘˝˘ˇ˘˘˘ˇˇˆˇ˘ ˘˛ˇ˝˘˚˚#˘˛˘˚˘˘ 
˘ˇ˘˚˛˛˘ˆ˛ˇˇˇ ˚˘˘˚˘˘ˇ˛˘˙˘˝˘ˇ˘ˆ˘˛˙˘˝˘ˇ˘˘˝˘"˘˛˘˝˘ˇ ˘˘˘˚˛˘˚)˘˘ˆ˛˘˘ 
˘˛˘˛˘ˆˇ˚˘˘˘˘˚˘˘˘˘˛˛˚˘˚˝˚ˇ˘#˘˘˚ˆ˘˘˘˝˘˚˘ˆˆˇ˘ˆ 
˘˘˘ˆ˘˝˘˘˚"˘˘˚˘˚˘ˇ˘ˆ˘ˆ˘˚ˆ˛˚˛ˆ˚˘˘˘˘˘˘˚˛˚˚ˆ#˘ˇˇˆˇ˘˝˘˘ˇ˚˘ˇˇ˘˛˛˚ ˚˘˘˘ˇ˚˘˘ˇ˘˘˚ˆ˘*˘ 
˘˘ˇ˘˚ˇ˘˙˘˚ˇ˘˘˘˙˙˘˘˚˚˘˘˝˘˘˘˛˛˘ˇˇ˚˘˛#˘ˆ˘˘ˇ˘˚˘ˇˇ˘˘ˇˆˇ˘$%&˘ˆ˘˛˘˚˘,
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I had the same issue and here is how I solved it.
In the newer docs of Py2PDF there is a section about [streaming data](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/streaming-data.html)

The example there looks like this:

```
from io import BytesIO

# Prepare example
with open("example.pdf", "rb") as fh:
    bytes_stream = BytesIO(fh.read())

# Read from bytes_stream
reader = PdfReader(bytes_stream)
```

Therefore, what I did instead was this:

```
import urllib
from io import BytesIO
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

NEW_PATH = 'https://example.com/path/to/pdf/online?id=123456789&date=2022060'

wFile = urllib.request.urlopen(NEW_PATH)
bytes_stream = BytesIO(wFile.read())

reader = PdfReader(bytes_stream)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import urllib, PyPDF2
import cStringIO

wFile = urllib.urlopen('https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf')
lFile = PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader( cStringIO.StringIO(wFile.read()) )
```

Because PyPDF2 does not work, there are a couple of solutions, however, require saving the file to disk.

**Solution 1** 
You can use ps2ascii (if you are using linux or mac ) or xpdf (Windows). Example of using xpdf:

```
import os
os.system('C:\\xpdfbin-win-3.03\\bin32\\pdftotext.exe C:\\xpdfbin-win-3.03\\bin32\\bitcoin.pdf bitcoin1.txt')
```

or

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\xpdfbin-win-3.03\\bin32\\pdftotext.exe',  'C:\\xpdfbin-win-3.03\\bin32\\bitcoin.pdf', 'bitcoin2.txt'])
```

**Solution 2** 
You can use one of online pdf to txt converter. Example of using [pdf.my-addr.com](http://pdf.my-addr.com/pdf-to-text-converter-tool.php)

```
import MultipartPostHandler
import urllib2


def pdf2text( absolute_path ):
    url = 'http://pdf.my-addr.com/pdf-to-text-converter-tool.php'

    params = {  'file' : open( absolute_path, 'rb' ),
                'encoding': 'UTF-8',
    }
    opener = urllib2.build_opener( MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler )
    return opener.open( url, params ).read()

print pdf2text('bitcoin.pdf')
```

Code of MultipartPostHandler you can find [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MultipartPostHandler/0.1.0). I tried to use the `cStringIO` instead `open()`, but it did not work.
Maybe it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Check my question update, any ideas on the funky text extraction?

Comment: I found a couple of solutions without the use of PyPDF2, but both methods require saving the file to disk. I updated my answer. Maybe it will be helpful for you.

Comment: "Funky text extraction" most likely has nothing to do with Python or the fact that this was not parsed from a local file. (To be sure, you could download the file manually and try with Acrobat Reader.) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649289/pdftextstripper-parsing-with-wrong-encoding for more on this.