# Tika can not read text correctly from PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, lucene, pdfbox, apache-tika

I am newbie in apache tika.

I have two PDF file with diffferent font but tika can not read correctly, One have Shruti font which is read correctly using tika but another one file have lmg-rupen font which is not read properly from tika, is there any specific font reading by tika?

below is my code snippest:

```
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata(); 
FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(file);

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
IOUtils.copy(inputstream, out); 
byte[] textBytes = out.toByteArray(); 
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(textBytes);
ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, pcontext);

LanguageDetector lDetector = new OptimaizeLangDetector().loadModels();
LanguageResult detect = lDetector.detect(handler.toString());
System.out.println("Language: " +detect); // Got languge 'de' but document languge is 'gu'

System.out.println(handler.toString()); // If font is Shruti content print correctly but font is LMG-RUPE than it gives wrong output
```

Comment: tika has some limitation like it cannot read more than 1 lakh characters. What is the size of your file?

Comment: File is not big its just 84KB issue with the font like i created file with font Shruti its read correctly but same content file i written in Lmg-Rupen font it gives me a wrong output.

Comment: Did you [try following the PDF troubleshooting instructions from Apache Tika](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika#PDF_Text_Problems)? If not, what happens when you do?

Comment: Thanks for Reply...
Gagravarr, I tried that but same issue i got.

TilmanHausherr: 

1st pdf working fine but 2nd pdf not get expected output

1) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Sse_x7pvrqRnRETzNsUk1BY0k

2) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Sse_x7pvrqVC0zb

Comment: @GopalBhalala second link doesn't work. I suspect you accidentally cut off the URL, it is much shorter.

Comment: @Gagravarr it would be nice if the guide could mention that if the text extraction doesn't work with Adobe Reader, it usually won't work with PDFBox. Similar to this: https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/faq.html#notext

Comment: @TilmanHausherr--https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Sse_x7pvrqVC0zb2NqTzNvYVU

Comment: @GopalBhalala The fonts in your second PDF claim to be **WinAnsiEncoding** encoded; thus, they claim to contain the Latin characters you see upon extraction (and also upon copying from Adobe Reader). Furthermore the document claims its language is **en-US**. While the PDF *appears* to have Shruti content in a viewer, internally it only uses Western European characters. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17651777/1729265).

Comment: If your question was about a PDF library (e.g. PDFBox, iText, ...), I'd close it as a duplicate to the one I linked to. I don't know Tika well enough, though. If it has an option to extract text from PDFs using OCR instead of using the intrinsic PDF information, then that would be the adequate answer instead.

Comment: The other document contains proper information indicating the actual characters to extract the text as. But it also forbids text extraction for anything but accessibility. If Tika extracts it, this is a questionable feature.